# showing table after one table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables in my DB and all tables have same columns.
for example:

table1

```
id  name  age  city   
1   Van   18    NY
```

table2

```
id  name  age  city  
1   Ben   23    LA
```

I want to show these tables in my dashboard  one after one like

NewTable

```
id  name  age     city   
1   Van   18      NY              
1   Ben   23      LA
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic sql

Use `UNION` if you want to get an output free of duplicates (kind of `distinct`)

Use `UNION ALL` if you want get an output with all records from all tables.

```
select id, name, age, city from table1
union -- or union all...
select id, name, age, city from table2
```